# Zxing project as library in a project won't build

Tags: android, zxing

( again ) I want to use the ZXing library in my project, I followed this tutorial
http://damianflannery.wordpress.com/2011/06/13/integrate-zxing-barcode-scanner-into-your-android-app-natively-using-eclipse/
[ only difference I'm using netbeans ]after building zxing android project and marking it as a library, I wanted to od it as a library in my own project. After doing it, I can't build it. It looks like the R file can't be created in both [library and myProject ] for example:

```
 error: constant expression required
        case R.id.zxinglib_auto_focus:
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can't be used as a library project directly, since it was not intended to be used as a library project, and this is generally discouraged. Please see my comments on that same post.

http://damianflannery.wordpress.com/2011/06/13/integrate-zxing-barcode-scanner-into-your-android-app-natively-using-eclipse/#comment-159

Comment: where can i ask my queries about scanner ? pls mention the link

Comment: StackOverflow? Mailing list? See the project site.

Comment: did not find @Sean Owen

Answer (score -1):

Try again after clean your project.It may happen that eclipse has not created ids of the view which you are using..

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3827393/java-switch-statement-constant-expression-required-but-it-is-constant