# Android App with its Barcode Scanner issue with Zxing resources

Tags: android, zxing, barcode-scanner, android-library

I am trying to implement Barcode scanner within my APP building it out of ZXING sources.

I have taken the latest available Zxing sources and now I have it as a Android Library Project. I also have successfully referred this Library from my application.

However at run time I am getting resources not found exception.

```
                 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity              
                  ComponentInfo{com.android.m2m/com.google.zxing.client.android.CaptureActivity}:
                  android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/xml/preferences.xml from  
                  drawable resource ID #0x7f050000
```

I have mentioned about the CaptureActivity in my Applications's Manifest XML also..

```
            <activity 
 android:name="com.google.zxing.client.android.CaptureActivity"
android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
android:screenOrientation="landscape"
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden" >
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN" />

    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
</intent-filter>
           </activity>
```

Is there anything that i am suppose to do ,so that the resources within the Zxing sources can be picked up ?

Answer (score 1):

I got the solution.

The problem is the source of zxing is not intended to be used as a Library..Got the answer by Sean in the below thread.

[Zxing project as library in a project won't build](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13028945/zxing-project-as-library-in-a-project-wont-build/13032194#13032194)

I tried bridling my app within this CaptureActivity project adding my activity and resources and modifying its manifest File accordingly.

Answer (score -1):

Are you using the R class from the ZXing in your activity code ? Sometimes it's just an import problem.