# Zxing 2.2 and R.id error

Tags: android, qr-code, zxing

I would like to integrate zxing into my app.
I'm importing project, set it as library, change target to API 7, download zxing-core-2.2.jar, copy it to /libs and add this jar in Java Building Path as library.

But there are still some errors:

[image: Zxing errors]
All of them are in switch statements and depend on R.id. for example:

```
switch (item.getItemId()) {
  case R.id.menu_share:
```

Eclipse error description:

> case expressions must be constant expressions

there is a info dialog:

[image]
Any idea what I'm doing wrong or how to fix it?

Comment: You're not intended to use this is a library. Use core/, not android/. This is the ultimate cause.

Comment: But I can't import stuff from core/ - I tried import as Existing Android Code into workspace, and Existing project into workspace - both without success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As explained in the dialog you have shown, R.id.menu_settings is now "*no longer constant*", which means it cannot be used in a switch. the dialog also provides the solution, instead of

```
switch (item.getItemId()) {
  case R.id.menu_share:
      //do something
      break;
  case xxx:
      ...
}
```

You should do this:

```
if(item.getItemId()==R.id.menu_share) {
      //do something
} else if (item.getItemId()==xxx) {
      //do something
}
```

Just follow the instruction and you should be fine.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the source of zxing is not intended to be used as a Library..
Please see the answer by Sean in the below thread.

[Zxing project as library in a project won't build](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13028945/zxing-project-as-library-in-a-project-wont-build/13032194#13032194)

I tried bridling my app within this CaptureActivity project adding my activity and resources and modifying its manifest File accordingly.