# even when use constans : case expressions must be constant expressions

Tags: android, constants, adt, final

```
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case Constants.EXIT :   
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
            intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            startActivity(intent);
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
```

and the Constants class :

```
public  class Constants {

    private Constants() {
    }

    public static final int EXIT = R.id.mExit;

}
```

what am i missing ? "menuExitButton " isn't constant ?

Comment: Try to use `if else` in place of `switch` and check if it works.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java switch statement: Constant expression required, but it IS constant](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3827393/java-switch-statement-constant-expression-required-but-it-is-constant)

Comment: Interesting.. Just wondering why are you not using `R.id.mExit` directly like `case R.id.mExit` ?

Comment: yes . i know i can use if else .  i am trying to avoid it and understand why my contants isnt consider as one .

Answer (score 0):

If the `R.id.mExit` comes from a libary project resource file, it's not a constant expression. Initializing a `static final` variable with a non-constant expression does not make the variable itself constant.

For further informationa about contant variable initialization, see the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3827424/101361) linked by @still_learning in comments.

Move the resource that declares the identifier to the main app project so it becomes a constant variable that can be used in a `switch` expression, or just replace the `switch` with an `if`-`else`.

Comment: it is not from library . is a simple menu from my xml .