# Using string from resource XML in Switch?

Tags: java, android, switch-statement, android-resources

New to Android here, so I apologize if this is a simplistic question.

I am attempting to use a switch based on string resources in my XML. It would look something like this:

```
switch (myStringVariable) {
    case getResources().getString(R.string.first_string):
         break;
    case getResources().getString(R.string.second_string):
         break;
    case getResources().getString(R.string.third_string):
         break;
    default:
         break;
}
```

Unfortunately, this won't work. The error that I get is "Constant expression required".

Is there a semi-elegant way to go about this, without having to do something like create 3 String objects and assign the string resources to each object? I feel like I'm missing something obvious, so any assistance would be great!

Thanks :)

Comment: the `if else if` construct

Comment: Assigning the string objects these values still doesn't work, right? The values are decided at run time, not compile time?

Answer (score 5):

Well, first of all, the version of Java that Android is based on does not support String switch statements, so generally you have to use `if/else` blocks instead.

**EDIT:** String switch statements are supported if you use JDK 1.7 and later

I'm not sure what your use case is, but if you have the resource ID of `myStringVariable`, which is an `int`, you can do a switch over that:

```
switch (myStringResId) {
case R.string.first_string:
     break;
case R.string.second_string:
     break;
case R.string.third_string:
     break;
default:
     break;
}
```

Comment: *not support String switch statements*, that's not true

Comment: Oh wow, thanks for pointing that one out. Last time I tried doing a String switch on android was in 2012 before we could compile with JDK 1.7.

Answer (score 4):

Well, it's not the most elegant way, but you can use if - else if statements instead of switch - case:

```
if (myStringVariable.equals(getString(R.string.first_string))) {
    // do something
} else if (myStringVariable.equals(getString(R.string.second_string))) {
    // do something
} else if (myStringVariable.equals(getString(R.string.third_string))) {
    // do something
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You're not missing something Android-related but Java-related instead.

Check this answer about how Java manages the Switch statement:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/3827424/2823516

You'll have to use the non elegant solution you mentioned. But who says is not elegant? Is what you should do, and that makes it elegant.