# switch case from string resource

Tags: java, android, switch-statement

I'm getting started with an Android project and I encountered this issue.

I'm trying to create a switch where the cases are string got with

```
case getString(R.string.myString): ...
```

but I'm getting a

```
Constant expression required
```

error.

I didn't want to create a cascade of if statements (this wouldn't require constant values, but it's less readable) so, is there a way to have a switch with strings taken from the strings.xml file?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: You cannot use switch case for this. Better use if else

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29541914/using-string-from-resource-xml-in-switch

Comment: Wow, I was wondering if I was missing something, but it's indeed not possible then. Also thanks @faran.javed for the link, I searched with many search terms but still couldn't find that question.

Comment: You can't do that, because `getString()` needs context and it finds its value after creating the activity or current context while `case` needs constant.

Answer (score 0):

It simply mean `switch` case allow only constant values.

[Here is a good example](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/abhinaba/2006/12/13/why-can-we-only-use-constants-in-a-switch-case-statement/) to show why switch only allow constants only.

You can use `if-else` statement for this purpose.

Comment: "This rule is followed in every language."
Javascript and Typescript also allow variable values in switch cases.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of getting String from resource (string.xml) file.
Define that String in Constant.java class as below:-

```
public static final String DOWNLOAD_DOCUMENTS = "com.android.providers.downloads.documents";
```

and use that Constant field in switch block :-

```
switch(input) {
   case DOWNLOAD_DOCUMENTS :
    // your logic 
   break;
}
```