# Constant expression required in switch statement

Tags: java, android, switch-statement

I want to use global constants in a switch statement. I wrote the constants in a Singleton called `ColorManager` in this way

```
public static final int blue = 3;
public static final int red = 5;
public static final int black = 7;
```

in my `HomeActivity` I wrote this code

```
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
    ColorManager cm = ColorManager.getInstance(this);
    switch (requestCode) {
        case cm.blue: {
        }
        case cm.red: {
        }
        case cm.black: {
        }
    }
}
```

But I get an error in the switch statement:

> Constant expression required

The values are final so constant, I don't understand why I get this error. I found similar topics but in all cases the properties was not declared as final.

Comment: use `ColorManager.blue` and so on, instead of `cm.blue`

Comment: there is no constant keyword in java. Final does not mean constant

Comment: read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3827393/java-switch-statement-constant-expression-required-but-it-is-constant

Comment: take care of static fields

Comment: There's no need to put curly brackets (`{` and `}`) around `case` block. You should either use `break;` or `return` from exiting the case. If you don't do that, the commands under the next `case` will be executed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It will compile if you access your static final fields statically; e.g. `case ColorManager.blue:`. If you try and access then from a variable `cm`, then you're preventing the compiler recognising them as compile-time constants.

Answer (score 0):

Use ClassName.variable i.e ColorManager.red

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {

    switch (requestCode) {
        case ColorManager.blue: {
        }
        case ColorManager.red: {
        }
        case ColorManager.black: {
        }
    }
}
```