# Constant Expression Required: why?

Tags: java

I initialise a global array of Strings like so:

```
    private static final String[] foods = new String[]{"Pasta", "Beef", "Soup", "Chicken"};
```

And I use foods[0] in a switch statement. Says it requires a constant expression. What is not constant about this?

Comment: You can write `foods[0] = null;`. It's simply not a constant.

Comment: can you show us your switch statement please?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java switch statement: Constant expression required, but it IS constant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3827393/java-switch-statement-constant-expression-required-but-it-is-constant)

Answer (score 3):

The reference to the array, `foods`, is constant, but you could easily have written, somewhere in your program:

```
foods[0] = "abc";
```

Thus `foods[0]` is not a constant.

Comment: I would mention that constant expressions are enumerated in https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se9/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.28

Comment: Okay - how do I fix it / what do I need to understand to be able to fix it?

Comment: @Edwin show us the switch. You can probably do it without the switch. Or, define the array elements using constants, and reference the constant in the switch.