# How to fix switch statement "Constant expression required" two strings

Tags: java, android

So im trying to make a counter and im using a switch statement

Here's the Code im trying:

```
 private View.OnClickListener clickListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
      @Override
      public void onClick(View view) {
          switch (PIP1) {
              case PI1:
                  Counter++
                  break;
          }
      }
  };
```

Its inside a button:
Im getting an error "Constant expression required" at case PI1.
I take PIP1 and PI1 like that from another activity:

```
  PIP1 = getIntent().getStringExtra("PlayerText");
  PI1 = getIntent().getStringExtra("Player1Text");
```

Comment: Please show how you declare `PI1`.

Comment: I get PI1 from another activity is a String and PIP1 too.

Comment: I didn't ask you to describe it, I asked you to *show* it. There are strict requirements on what  allows a variable to be considered a constant, so the details are important.

Comment: It needs to be a compile time constant. `String`s are hashed and then an integer switch over the hash code will be constructed by the compiler, with some additional checking in each case that the strings match.

Comment: Sorry can you give me a example i dont really know what do you mean

Comment: I guess he wanted to see how do you declare (define) PIP1 variable. For example:  `public static final String PIP1 = "pip1value";`

Comment: You can't put something that is not a constant whose value is known at compile tile into switch(). That's what the error means. And what Andy means is that you should edit your question and post the code where PIP is declared instead of vaguely describing the code. When answering a question about code, seeing the code helps a lot. Guessing it based on a description doesn't help as much.

Comment: Well, if he takes it from another activity, then it cannot be a constant for sure. For further explanaition of `java` constants and `switch` block check: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3827424/3479154

Comment: @jpact that's not true. Constants can be defined in any class.

Comment: @AndyTurner obviously, thats true. I was thinking about getting it at runtime, through `Intent` extras for example.

Comment: you have only one case, why not use just an `if`?

Answer (score 0):

I try what @jpact said instead of declearing them like that

```
 String PIP1;
 String PI1;
```

You just do this:

```
 public static final String PIP1 = "PlayerText";
 public static final String PI1 = "Player1Text";
```

Player1Text and PlayerText is the Keys.

Again thanks to @jpact

Comment: If both `PIP1` and `PI1` are constants, there is no point in the switch.