# Compare string with enum value using switch in Java

Tags: java, enums

Note: This is not a duplicate of [Java switch statement: Constant expression required, but it IS constant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3827393/java-switch-statement-constant-expression-required-but-it-is-constant) because the solution to that link was already applied here.

---

In a Cordova App with typescript I use this enum to send my actions =

typescript

```
enum PluginActions {
   PICK = "PICK",
   PICK_MULTIPLE = "PICK_MULTIPLE"
}
```

I send that to cordova and in Java I get that as an `action` string variable in my method.

```
@Override
  public boolean execute(String action, JSONArray inputs, CallbackContext callbackContext) throws JSONException {

  }
```

There I also have an enum.

Java

```
enum PickerActions {
  PICK, PICK_MULTIPLE
}
```

I want to compare the typescript `PluginActions` vs the java `PickerActions`.

Using `if` I can do it using:

`if (action.equals(PickerActions.PICK.name())) { }`

but I wan to do it with a switch so I can easily add more actions

```
  switch (action) {
    case PickerActions.PICK.name():
      JSONObject filters = inputs.optJSONObject(0);
      this.chooseFile(filters, callbackContext);
      return true;
    default:
    Log.w(this.LOGGER_TAG, "No function was found for " + action);
    return false;      
  }
```

But I get an error there: `error: constant string expression required`

Is there a way to use an enum string name in a switch statement?

Edit:

As per @Arnaud recommendation I casted the value of the enum in this way:

```
final PickerActions pickerAction = FilePickerActions.valueOf(action);

    switch (pickerAction ) {
      case PickerActions.PICK:
        JSONObject filters = inputs.optJSONObject(0);
        this.chooseFile(filters, callbackContext);
        return true;
      default:
      Log.w(this.LOGGER_TAG, "No function was found for " + action);
      return false;      
    }
```

But I get another error there regarding `case PickerAction.Pick`

> error: an enum switch case label must be the unqualified name of an enumeration constant

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java switch statement: Constant expression required, but it IS constant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3827393/java-switch-statement-constant-expression-required-but-it-is-constant)

Comment: Switch on `PickerActions.valueOf(action)`, and put actual enum values in the `case` blocks : `case PickerActions.PICK` .

Comment: @GauravJeswani that link shows a similar problem but the solution is to use Enums, what I am already doing.

Comment: @Arnaud I try it but I get another error. `error: an enum switch case label must be the unqualified name of an enumeration constant` (I have updated my question with that info)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`java.lang.String`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) values in your [`java.lang.Enum`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Enum.html) and test against it in your switch cases.

But, like [@SpencerSprowls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58130592/compare-string-with-enum-value-using-switch-in-java#comment118160180_58130825) said in comments, it will throw an [`java.lang.IllegalArgumentException`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/IllegalArgumentException.html) if you use a value that doesn't match with any values of your [`java.lang.Enum`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Enum.html).

Thus, adding a default case in your switch is useless. To avoid throwing unwanted exceptions, you can convert your [`java.lang.Enum`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Enum.html) values to an [`java.util.EnumMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/EnumMap.html) and check if it matches existing values before the switch with [`EnumMap#containsValue`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/EnumMap.html#containsValue-java.lang.Object-)

```
private enum PickerActions {
    PICK("PICK"),
    PICK_MULTIPLE("PICK_MULTIPLE");
    private final String value;
    PickerActions(final String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return value;
    }
}
    
private static boolean test(String test) {
     switch (PickerActions.valueOf(test)) {
        case PICK:
            //
            return true;
        case PICK_MULTIPLE:
            //
            return false;
        // default:
            // This will never happen
            // return false;      
    }
}
```

[Here is a working example](https://tio.run/##lVLBbtswDD3bX0H4JKOdvV0bDFix9RCsWQK0OxXDoNhMolSWDIl2Ngz59kyyZcNp00N5kUQ@PpKP2vOWf9iXz6eTqGptCPbOkQmdzZd3fwqsSWg1i6cxEhVm3xrD3wjNlSWuaBbHdbOWooBCcmthwYWCf3EMzkLA4cgdrRYlVC7MHsgItX36BdxsberQECxw@gxX6/PwzpQ@sHQ2wh7@WsIq0w1ltWMiqRihJZas5l@/J@kEORCiKt9FlyyQdrqEMswPN5BcDWJka6QDomJdm9eePM22SD@40izNP33s7CqBSkgpLBZalTYJBY9BGiNaTuhymwpWonhGc1t4cuvkiPwcwzTX/fP34uf943x1f9f7x6fnHScZWDdCcQm9zNBy2aADRWdl2GuM30TkaWgnbNa5nGghPXKNR1@WLRojSoyjsNuQT7q/sJHDIDVGTbIvDB8@xlpriVxBt8OB0N2nP8MeBBU7YGcz9D0uN9320yncW8Etgtfq5sztLc9fuUK/ZHy7F2lGyd/Dt@HSviDMcyhxwxtJl4jg0YkPB/dzQKFTG3a8rlFdQp6V6L0j7Bi/3cgxPp5O/wE/ujj5oUDaSMej248tYWLwkGif5h1aKysMufuHTTAy/Q87A1qk1uo3qDCSU@VpL1bGKBQa4msOSP/fLwa4vaRyA@ysm77SeR1XoEhKb6VwCGFa4@S4tDZpzpMkOZVKNlYanRXWolX0LubsVXptotVCuYQLTR@yw/H4Bw)

Comment: This will throw an exception if the String does not correspond to a valid Enum. There is no use case where the default will ever be hit.

Answer (score 2):

error: an enum switch case label must be the unqualified name of an enumeration constant,
You should not use case PickerActions.PICK but to only case PICK as below,

```
public class MainClass {
   enum Choice { Choice1, Choice2, Choice3 }
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      Choice ch = Choice.Choice1;

      switch(ch) {
         case Choice1:
            System.out.println("Choice1 selected");
            break;
         case Choice2:
            System.out.println("Choice2 selected");
            break;
         case Choice3:
            System.out.println("Choice3 selected");
             break;
      }
   }
}
```