# switch case with integer resources

Tags: java, android

I would like to use the switch command with choice defined in a resource file but I have the error:
error: constant expression required

Do you have any suggestion?

ressource file integers.xml

```
<integer name="readID">0x21</integer>
<integer name="readRevision">0x22</integer>
```

java file:

```
switch (cmd) {
case getResources().getInteger(R.integer.readID):
    break;
case getResources().getInteger(R.integer.readRevision):
    Log.d(TAG, "case revision");
    break;
```

Comment: the ids or readId and readVersion resources will change every time your build you app and it's not possible for a switch two have values that could change. You should place this values not on integers.xml but in constants values for exemple or anywhere

Answer (score 1):

In Java the case part of a switch needs a constant value.

Java expects with getResources().getInteger(R.integer.readID) since it is a method call that the value may change at runtime.
See [Java switch statement: Constant expression required, but it IS constant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3827393/java-switch-statement-constant-expression-required-but-it-is-constant)
for more information.

You may use an if, else if, else construct.

Answer (score 0):

Just define your integers as static constants in a separate file (Constants.java perhaps).

Constants

```
public class Constants{
public static final int READ_ID = 0x11;
public static final int READ_REVISION = 0x22;
}
```

Switch

```
switch (cmd) {
        case Constants.READ_ID:

            break;
        case Constants.READ_REVISION:

            break;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
private int getInt(@IntegerRes int res){
    return context.getResources().getInteger(res);
}
```

For example:

```
switch (cmd) {
case getInt(R.integer.readID):
    break;
case getInt(R.integer.readRevision):
    Log.d(TAG, "case revision");
    break;}
```

Comment: sorry, it did not change anything: error: constant expression required