# Is Build.VERSION.SDK_INT constant expression?

Tags: java, android, constant-expression

Given the boolean and a variable set based on it:

```
private static final boolean IS_ANDROID_Q = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q;
private static final int OPTION = IS_ANDROID_Q ? 0 : 1;
```

There is a switch-case statement:

```
public static void foo(int option) {
    switch (option) {
        case OPTION: break;
    }
}
```

The compiler complains about `constant expression required` error on `OPTION` variable. However, when I changed `Build.VERSION.SDK_INT` to other int values, it did not show any error message.

The [official documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.VERSION#SDK_INT) states that `Build.VERSION.SDK_INT` is declared as `static final int`.

Are there any conditions required for constant expression other than specified in the [oracle documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.28)?

Or did I miss something?

UPDATE 1:

The reason I did not think this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3827393/java-switch-statement-constant-expression-required-but-it-is-constant) solved my problem is that

```
private static final boolean IS_ANDROID_Q = {with some int} >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q;
private static final int OPTION = IS_ANDROID_Q ? 0 : 1;
```

this runs perfectly fine.

UPDATE 2:

There are mentions of [Java switch statement: Constant expression required, but it IS constant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3827393/java-switch-statement-constant-expression-required-but-it-is-constant) possibly being a solution to this question, which I disagree with. If you take a look at the accepted answer for the question, he says that

> ... the Foo.BA* variables do not have initializers, and hence do not qualify as "constant variables". ...

However as you can see, the variables I declared, `IS_ANDROID_Q` and `OPTIONS`, do have **initializers**. I initially stated that the change of `Build.VERSION.SDK_INT` to some constant `int` value led to the successful build.

So the only remaining question is whether or not `Build.VERSION.SDK_INT` is a constant expression. To give a rationale, a constant expression can only be valid when it is initialized with a compile-time constant expression. You can find this in the question I linked above.

This is the whole reason why I named this question "Is `Build.VERSION_SDK_INT` constant expression?". It is not about whether my variables have been initialized.

Hence, I do not think this question is a duplicate one.

Comment: It should be constant, not an expression. OPTION is an expression. 0 or 1 is constant.

Comment: @AccessDenied can you explain it in more detail?

Comment: Did you check this already - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3827393/java-switch-statement-constant-expression-required-but-it-is-constant

Comment: @AccessDenied without changing `OPTION`, but changing `Build.VERSION.SDK_INT`, the build successfully completed.

Comment: IS_ANDROID_Q is not a compile time constant. That's why you see this error.

Comment: @MukeshKeshu, @AccessDenied I checked the post already. The reason I'm confused is because `IS_ANDROID_Q = 30 >= Build.VERSION_CODE.Q` runs successfully.

Comment: @PHD `IS_ANDROID_Q = 30 >= Build.VERSION_CODE.Q` is a constant as it's always true.

Comment: @GavinWright So do you mean `Build.VERSION.SDK_INT` is not a constant expression?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Build.VERSION.SDK_INT` is not a constant expression because it is a simple name of a non constant variable. A [constant variable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.12.4) can only be initialized with the constant expression. A constant expression cannot include a function call as part of its initialization statement and here we see a call to `SystemProperties.getInt(..)`.

Hence you cannot use `Build.VERSION.SDK_INT` as a label in a switch statement and other places where only constant expressions are acceptable.

Answer (score 0):

I searched for [source code for Android SDK](https://github.com/AndroidSDKSources/android-sdk-sources-for-api-level-29/blob/master/android/os/Build.java#L267) and confirmed that `Build.VERSION.SDK_INT` is not a constant expression.

Here is the definition of `Build.VERSION.SDK_INT`:

```
public static final int SDK_INT = SystemProperties.getInt(
        "ro.build.version.sdk", 0);
```

Comment: Just want to add the definition of a constant expression: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.28