# Use Enum with switch statement: constant expression required error

Tags: java

I've defined an enumerated class "TestEnvEnum", and I've defined a class "ConfigInit" that calls the enumerated class.

```
public enum TestEnvEnum {
    ENV1("devEnv1"),
    ENV2("devEnv2"),
    ENV3("devEnv3");

    private final String name;

    TestEnvEnum(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return name;
    }
}


public class ConfigInit {
    static String envIndex = "1";
    static String envProps = System.getProperties().getProperty("env");
    public static void scfInit() {
        switch (envProps) {
            case TestEnvEnum.ENV2.name():  //error: Constant expression required
                envIndex = "2";
                break;
            case TestEnvEnum.ENV3.name():  //error: Constant expression required
                envIndex = "3";
                break;
            default:
                envIndex = "1";
        }
    }
}
```

Question: If I using Enum, so case TestEnvEnum.ENV2.name() and case TestEnvEnum.ENV3.name() will prompt "Constant expression required".

If I changed them to case "devEnv2" and case "devEnv3", the program will run correctly.

I want to know how I should use Enum in my program to avoid such an error. Pls help me.

Comment: You should use `if` instead of `switch`.

Answer (score 2):

You can change it to something like this:

```java
public enum TestEnvEnum {
    ENV1("devEnv1"),
    ENV2("devEnv2"),
    ENV3("devEnv3");

    private final String name;

    TestEnvEnum(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return name;
    }

    public static TestEnvEnum byName(String name) { //You may change the return type to Optional<TestEnvEnum> to avoid NPE
        for (TestEnvEnum value : values()) {
            if(value.getName().equals(name)) { //equalsIgnoreCase should be used if you don't care about the capitalization
                return value;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}

public class ConfigInit {
    static String envIndex = "1";
    static String envProps = System.getProperties().getProperty("env");
    public static void scfInit() {
        TestEnvEnum testEnvEnum = TestEnvEnum.byName(envProps);
        switch (testEnvEnum) {
            case ENV2:
                envIndex = "2";
                break;
            case ENV3:
                envIndex = "3";
                break;
            default:
                envIndex = "1";
        }
    }
}
```

I would recommend you to read this post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3827424/8052043) which explains really good why this happens.

Comment: `if(name.equals(name))` is always true.

Comment: @CodeMatrix  Why return NULL for byName method ?

Comment: @binbjz what you would like to return instead? It won't be nice to have per default e. g. `devEnv1`.

Answer (score -1):

In your use case, it is responding with correct exception as you are passing `envProp` which is of type String so all the cases will we defined with string type  but in your case you are evaluating the value by calling `name()` method which is unsupported so either you need to pass Enum type the switch so that it looks for enums otherwise convert your enum values to a string and use strig constants in place of expression.

Note:  The case labels must all be explicit enum values, not expressions that evaluate to enum values.

e.g.

```
enum TestEnvEnum {
    ENV1("devEnv1"),
    ENV2("devEnv2"),
    ENV3("devEnv3");

    private final String name;

    TestEnvEnum(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

     public static TestEnvEnum enumValue(String name) {
     return Arrays.stream(values()).filter(value -> name.equalsIgnoreCase(value.name)).findFirst()
            .orElse(null);
}

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return name;
    }
}


public class SampleEnum {
    static String envIndex = "1";
    
    public static void scfInit() {
        TestEnvEnum envProps = TestEnvEnum.enumValue(System.getProperties().getProperty("env"));
        switch (envProps) {
            case ENV2:  
                envIndex = "2";
                break;
            case ENV3:  
                envIndex = "3";
                break;
            default:
                envIndex = "1";
        }
    }
}
```

The above example will work.

Comment: OP is expecting "devEnv1", "devEnv2", or "devEnv3" as the value of `System.getProperties().getProperty("env")`.

Comment: Yes  and may I ask you what is incorrect in the mentioned answer for improvement

Comment: `TestEnvEnum.valueOf("ENV1")` returns `TestEnvEnum.ENV1`, but `TestEnvEnum.valueOf("devEnv1")` throws an `IllegalArgumentException`.