# String case expressions must be constant expressions

Tags: java

I have the following:

```
public class Asd
{
    static final String VERSION = "version";
    static final String ECHO    = "echo".toUpperCase();
    public Asd()
    {
        String key = ECHO;
        switch (key)
        {
            case VERSION:
                break;

            case ECHO:
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

I get a compiler error that `case ECHO:` is not a constant expression. The designation `final static` defines a constant.

The constant `ECHO` will resolve from `"echo"` to `"ECHO"` when the class is instantiated. By the time the switch/case is evaluated, `ECHO` does equal `"ECHO"` and cannot be changed.

Or does a switch/case with String have some special background pointers to a String?

Because using

```
public class Asd
{
    static final int VERSION = 1;
    static final int ECHO    = 1 + 2;

    public Asd()
    {
        int key = ECHO;

        switch (key)
        {
            case VERSION:
                break;

            case ECHO:
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Is error free even though `1 + 2` must be evaluated.

Comment: That should answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3827393/java-switch-statement-constant-expression-required-but-it-is-constant/3827488

Comment: See the Java Language Specification for _constant expressions_: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.28

Comment: @MirekPluta The referred question uses ```int```, so does not apply.

Comment: @LouisWasserman I have used this same method```toUpperCase()``` in static final before, but only when doing ```if/else``` constructs. Thought I'd give the new case String functionality a try

Comment: It must be ***compile time constants***. `1+2` and `"a"+"b"` the compiler can evaluate, but a function call  (`toUpperCase()`) not. You could do `switch (key.toLowerCase())` instead. The compiler generates branches based on value comparisons.

Comment: @JoopEggen I kind of thought that is what is was. I am used to using static function calls in the static final construct, and it does work elsewhere else. Thanks

Comment: BTW the convention is `private static final String`; that is `final` last before (generic) type.

Comment: @JoopEggen Yeah I know actually. Typing too fast :-)

Comment: @MirekPluta Please remove your duplicate flag. The referred to question is about switch/case where the cases are integers, NOT Strings. My question is about String types, and therefore new