# Expression must be constant in case expressions java

Tags: java, android

I have an switch statement to create a bottom navigation view so that it can switch between all three sections. However, the switch statements comes up with an error, Constant Expression required. Is there any solution?

```
binding.bottomNavigationView.setOnItemSelectedListener(item -> {

        switch (item.getItemId()) {

            case R.id.camera:
                replaceFragment(new CameraFragment());
                break;
            case R.id.translate:
                replaceFragment(new TranslateFragment());
                break;
            case R.id.audio:
                replaceFragment(new AudioFragment());
                break;
        }


        return true;
    });
}
```

***************************UPDATE************************************

Changed it to an if statement, setting item.getItemId() as an int.

```
binding.bottomNavigationView.setOnItemSelectedListener(item -> {
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.camera) {
            replaceFragment(new CameraFragment());
        } else if (id == R.id.translate) {
            replaceFragment(new TranslateFragment());
        } else if (id == R.id.audio) {
            replaceFragment(new AudioFragment());
        }
```

Comment: Maybe you could take a look at this? https://stackoverflow.com/a/3827424/16034206

Comment: really? How did you do it? Maybe you could post the answer or add an update

Comment: I edited the question with the answer